# provisioning iPhone application on actual device

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I am a registered apple developer (I paid the $99).

I cant find any simple step by step instructions now on how to get my iPhone application downloaded to my phone...

Answer (score 0):

Apple have great tutorials on their developer program website but this is also a very good one: http://programming4.us/mobile/876.aspx

Comment: and also this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development/